# Error while printing Fedex return lable

Tags: web-services, fedex

I am newbie to fedex web-services API.

I want to print the return label with the out bound shipment. I tried including below tag under  `RequestedShipment/SpecialServicesRequested` tag. but i am getting the error "Alternate sender not allowed with return shipments".

Here is my request look like..

```
<RequestedShipment>

    .
    .

    <SpecialServicesRequested>

        .
        .   

        <ReturnShipmentDetail>
            <ReturnType>PRINT_RETURN_LABEL</ReturnType>
        </ReturnShipmentDetail>

        .
        .

    </SpecialServicesRequested>

    .
    .

</RequestedShipment>
```

Thanks in advance...

**Update :** I am using fedex API 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When requesting return label, it should not have following two elements in request body.

LabelSpecification/ PrintedLabelOrigin/ Contact,

LabelSpecification/ PrintedLabelOrigin/ Address

Above elements are used to override return address from default value of shipping address.:)